# Can't continue for loop python

Tags: python

If any item in the dayhrslist does not have a hyphen;
(10p-6a, OFF, 5p-1a) it errors;
"ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

I'm sure I don't understand how to apply the except if that's the best choice for me.

A working example list is something like; (10p-6a, 2p-10p, 5p-1a) 
If the list is full like this it works fine.

I have tried a lot of variations of except:, continue, pass, but
can't figure them out to make them work.

This works:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("130x80+300+300")
content = Frame(root)

def showvframe(event):
    root.after(100)
    vframe.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nswe")
    vend.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nswe")

def hidevframe(event):
    vframe.configure(bg="green")
    root.after(100, vframe.grid_remove)

def hideonlyif():
    root.after(300)
    q = vframe.cget('bg')
    if q == "yellow":
        #print "passing"
        pass
    else:
        vframe.configure(bg="green")
        root.after(100, vframe.grid_remove)
        #print "elsing"

def startthread(event):        
    thread.start_new_thread( hideonlyif, ())         

def invframe(event):
    root.after(100)
    vframe.configure(bg="yellow")

vframe = Frame(content, height=60, width=60) 
vframe.bind('<Enter>', invframe)
vframe.bind('<Leave>', hidevframe)

vendlist = ["bird", "mouse", "cat"]
vend = Listbox(vframe, height=4)
for item in vendlist:
    vend.insert(END, item)

Bvendor = Button(content, text="b 1", width=5)
Bvendor.bind('<Enter>',showvframe)
Bvendor.bind('<Leave>',startthread)

content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nswe")
Bvendor.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="n")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for correctly formatting and indenting your code before expecting any kind of help. The way it currently is cannot possibly run.

Comment: Thank you. Hearing no objections I'm going to use this post to practice formatting after this. I know its possible to get it right.

Comment: If you get a chance tell me which method for pasting code in works best. The only time I got it to paste in well was when I copied what you had edited- pasted it to a plain text file- then copied and pasted it back here- it kept the same layout. But my attempts at copying and pasting straight from my .py are not good. Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Two things are important: 1. that you always add 4 spaces at the start - can easily be done with Ctrl-K - and 2. that you consistently use spaces *or* tabs and don't mix them. That may be a soure of problems if you keep mixing them inside your .py files, but that is not good as well: might confuse the interpreter, some editors and as well potential other readers who might operate with a different tab size.

Comment: Thank you. What is best the to do for an example that even if a line is cut down to it's shortest, it is still wrapped. Is there a normal way that makes it obvious it's wrapped or is it best to let it scroll sideways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to check would be:

```
if '-' in item:
    # parse
else:
    # don't do anything
```

Comment: This looks like a good idea and of course it does what I'm after.

Answer (score 5):

```
  try:
    starp,stoap = item.split('-')
  except ValueError:
    time1 = parser.parse(starp)
```

If a ValueError occurs, `starp` will not have been defined. So

```
time1 = parser.parse(starp)
```

raises a `UnboundLocalError` because the right-hand side references a variable (`starp`) which is not defined.

Comment: I need to learn about variable scope though so if I do need to solve something similar in the future I can -thanks